# Borrar mensaje tras un tiempo en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, time

¡Buenas!

Tengo un programa hecho para simular sistemas mecánicos, la interfaz gráfica la hice en tkinter. El tema es que de cara al usuario, no tengo nada que alerte sobre lo que va pasando al usar el programa, por ejemplo algo que al guardar cualquier dato, notifique que se ha guardado.

Por ello, puse un entry al que ir poniéndole lo que fuese pasando (a través de "xxx.set()"). El tema es que quiero buscar una forma de que, tras x segundos, el mensaje se borre automáticamente. Y a poder ser, que lo haga con alguna animación atenuándose o algo, no de golpe. En caso de no ser posible, con que tan solo desaparezca me conformo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que buscas es `threading`, que es un hilo de Python que se ejecute paralelamente, y pueda tener en cuenta el pasar del tiempo. En cuanto a la animación, lo único que se me ocurre es usar una `Progressbar` e ir desde el 100% hasta 0% (y cerrar la ventana), por lo que eso es lo que hice en el código:

```
import time, threading
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class Ventana:
    def __init__(self,tiempo):
        self.tl = tk.Tk()
        self.tl.title('Progreso')
        tk.Label(self.tl,text='Cargando').grid(column=0, row = 0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.tl)
        self.progress['value'] = 100
        self.progress.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        def activar():
            t = tiempo
            while t > 0:
                time.sleep(1)
                self.progress['value'] = ((t/tiempo)*100 - 10)
                t -= 1
            self.tl.destroy()
        th = threading.Thread(target=activar)
        th.start()
        self.tl.mainloop()

v = Ventana(5)
```

Lo que hace la línea `th = threading.Thread(target=activar)` es crear un `Thread` (hilo) que ejecute la función `activar`, la cual hace que el hilo "duerma" por un segundo (puedes modificar el intervalo, si lo haces también hazlo en el `t` cuando le resto 1, es para sabes cuánto falta) y actualice la barra de progreso. Cuando el tiempo llega a 0, se cierra la ventana principal (en realidad deberías hacerlo con un `tkinter.TopLevel()`, no con el `tkinter.Tk()`, yo lo hice para fines demostrativos).

Answer (score 0):

He estado buscando un ejemplo de un timer asíncrono. Este me parece genial, pero sigo buscando. La funcionalidad que necesito requiere de un reset. Supongo que así como hay un metodo start para el thread debe haber un finish o stop pero no los he encontrado.

Alguna sugerencia ...